# MongoDB: Relational Data which is only used in one context? (Collection vs. Schema)

Tags: json, database, mongodb, database-design, non-relational-database

I have a few people saved in my database. Sometimes teams are formed an I need to add a few people to a team. Some people won't have any team.

I will never need to access the teams separately, i.e. I only ever need to look at the teams when I am already looking at the people. So I thought of saving it all together. So instead of creating a new collection for teams, I thought it might be better to just nest it:

```
      people: [
      {
        name: "Jack",
        team: team_id_1,
      },
      {
        name: "John",
        team: null,
      }, 
      {
        name: "Jane",
        team: team_id_1,
      }, 
      ...
      ],

      teams: [
      {
        team_id: team_id_1
        color: "red",
      },
      ...
      ]
```

However, I do not know how I can now create this sort of relationship in mongo, and **assign a team_id to each of the person-objects *without it being a collection*.**

Someone here suggested to `Define user's team as a reference to team's collection and then populating it.` - but, as I undestand it, this means creating a separate model for my team, and turning team into its own separate collection. I would prefer to not do this, since I will never need to access this collection directly and don't want to go through one massive collection of teams, if I only ever need to access three teams and can easily keep them in the relevant object.

What would you advise me to do? Is this the wrong approach?

Comment: So you have a list of teams and you need to get all people in a certain team?

Comment: If you have a unique identifier for your team, you can use it as team's id.. otherwise use the default mongo id.

You could use mongoose to easily archive your goal... 
Define user's team as a reference to team's collection and then populating it. 

Read more about mongoose and population [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Comment: @Adam I have a list of people, and need to assign some of those people to teams. I create the teams on the spot, they do not exist beforehand.

Comment: @Ron537 thanks. but I would need to create a mongoose model for this, correct? (In the example you referenced, models are being used) My question is whether I can do this with Schemas only.

Comment: I understand your data structure, but I'm not understanding the purpose. What's stopping you from simply generating a team ID when defining a person? Why would this be a referencing problem if there is no Teams collection?